# Wix CopyFile to variable number of folders

Tags: wix

I'm building Wix installer for the plugin for a product that can have multiple installations on the computer - the number of instances is variable.

I would like to install my files into the plugin folder and then to search for product folders and then copy plugin files to those product folders.

Can this be accomplished without custom action?

Comment: You might need to consider what happens when another product instance is created after the plugin is installed. Some things are better solved within the application but I surmise that it's not your application.

Comment: It's not my app, and I can't attach plugin to the app setup. The user will have to rerun plugin setup if he/she installs a new instance of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, try a combination of Directory search (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directorysearch.html) and
copy file (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html) elements.